# How can we use a List from Java class that allow us this

Tags: java, list, libraries

How can we use a List from Java libraries that allow us to insert to any index. I tried using ArrayList but doesn't work. For example I want to insert at index 50, 40, 60. But not starting from 0. Cause i know you have to start at 0 right?

Comment: Do you want a list where you can insert anywhere, without filling up the indices before that?

Comment: Yes that is right. Also for example i am inserting to index 5 and 10 so the size would be 2. I don't want to extend the size since it's not efficient to do that and not going to work for me.

Comment: I tried List<Object> varname = new LinkedList<Object>(); still doesn't work

Comment: please do not add information in comments, use edit to put it in the question.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY-problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Care to share with us, what you are trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to be able to insert anywhere, you have a few options of how to do something like that. The first is just to insert `null`s until the list is filled up to the point you want. That's going to be pretty awkward though, so I wouldn't recommend it.

What I would recommend is dropping the requirement that it be a `List`. What you're describing sounds much more like a `Map` than a `List`. So I'd suggest you use a `TreeMap<Integer, V>`.

Instead of using `list.add(index, item)`, you'd use `map.put(index, item)`. This would likely do what you want, depending on hwo you want to use it. And, since `TreeMap` stays in order based on its key's natural ordering, iterating over it will be the same as order as if you used a list.

If you really wanted to, you could even write your own implementation of `List` which wraps the `TreeMap`. This would fulfill your requirement, although I really think that it's a bad idea. Doing this is going to be pretty atypical for a `List`, and might cause some problems in code that expects a regular `List`

Comment: yes i would do that definitely but the specs requires me to return a list with those data in the specified index.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a way to distinguish the object in the ArrayList is "useless" (e.g., an additional boolean field of the object indicating this), then we can first add non-null but "useless" objects in the list, and then insert "useful" objects using `add(int index, E element)` to any index.

Comment: yeah but that would increase the size which i don't want to do

Comment: @Sleek13 What do you mean by "size" - do you mean inserting a element will increase the size of the list (say, from 50 to 51), or do you mean the memory usage of the list?